# PUT request 403 Forbidden

Tags: laravel-4, apache2, mamp

Developing an API using laravel.

Getting 403 Forbidden on PUT request.

Works on a remote server but not locally. Using MAMP for the local server.

Here is my virtual host, I don't see anything off.

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/dg/Documents/Websites/domain.com/public_html/dev/public_html"
    ServerName domain.local
    ServerAlias www.domain.local
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog "/Users/dg/Documents/Websites/domain.com/public_html/dev/error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/dg/Documents/Websites/domain.com/public_html/dev/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>`

I've looked at other similar questions on SO but no solution yet.

Comment: The first question is where this 403 comes from, does the webserver or the laravel app denies the request? Have a look in your apache error- / access log and in your laravel log (app/storage/logs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://serverfault.com/questions/275512/put-request-results-in-403-forbidden-need-apache-to-allow-put-requests

Added the following to .htaccess at the document root:

`<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>`

Answer (score 3):

According to @drack's answer I edit my .htaccess using this code:

```
    <Limit GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
        Require all granted
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
        Require all denied
    </LimitExcept>
```

My complete .htaccess file is:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"
<Limit GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
    Require all granted
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
    Require all denied
</LimitExcept>
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
# END WordPress
```

And 403 error goes away in put request.

Answer (score 0):

In my vhosts file I put:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(HEAD|GET|POST|PUT)$ [NC]
```

This allowed it for me.  I tried all of the other solutions and nothing worked but this.