# 403 Error in woocommerce rest api put request

Tags: .htaccess, ionic3, put, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm working on Ionic prject using nodeJS and woocommerce as backend. When I try to modify a user using below code, I get 403 forbidden error! (user_id 143 exist in my woocommerce)

```
   this.WooCommerce = WC({
      url: "https://mmarket.ir",
      consumerKey: "ck_bd5########################fa",
      consumerSecret: "cs_b9######################c7",
      wpAPI: true,
      version: 'wc/v3'
    });

var data = {
  first_name: 'James'
};

this.WooCommerce.put('customers/143', data, function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

result:

```
PUT https://mmarket.ir/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/143 403 (Forbidden)
passwordreset.ts:152 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /wp-json/wc/v3/customers/143
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

my .htaccess file content:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
# END WordPress
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I edit my .htaccess using this code:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
    Require all granted
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
    Require all denied
</LimitExcept>
```

And 403 error goes away in put request.
[PUT request 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696539/put-request-403-forbidden/54051143#54051143)