# Getting 403 Forbidden on VueJS PUT requests

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx

Why am I getting a 403 forbidden error only on put request API from CentOS 7 vps server (while get/post are working well)?

The same piece works fine on a shared hosting server and from localhost.

I am using "Nginx + Varnish + Apache"

Whenever I try to execute any PUT request, this is the response:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /api/path/to/my/api on this server.

Comment: PUT, PATCH etc. requests aren't supported by default - try using POST/GET (you can pretty much do the same things with these).

Comment: can you add a route that is not working from your routes file ?

Comment: Why do you use 3 reverse proxies at the same time?

Comment: @Namoshek To get the best performance from VPS. A combo of these three can provide 65% of the total server where Apache alone provides only 35%.

Comment: Dear @JCode, Can you tell me why PUT, PATCH are not supported by default? I solved temporarily by calling them by POST request though.

Comment: @OrbachinUjbuk I'm not sure, I think it has something to do with the forms and how HTML handles serialization data - but I don't want to just guess.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use POST method along with  `_method`= `PUT` as a form data:

```
                let editUrl ="";                     
                 if (this.id) {
                        this.data._method = 'PUT';
                        this.data.id = this.id;
                        editUrl = editUrl + "/" + this.id;
                    }

                  axios.post(editUrl, this.data)
                    .then(resp => {

                    })
                    .catch(() => {

                    });
            }
```

Comment: That's wrong and does only account for HTML forms, as these don't support `PUT` and `PATCH`. Ajax requests and Laravel **do** support these HTTP methods.

Comment: If you use Laravel resource controller then it won't support.

Comment: Also wrong. Have a look at [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: Did you try consuming them from VueJs? I tried and faced that problem. From the front end you will call Post but actually it will execute PUT method in the back-end. `_method`=PUT will do the trick.

Comment: @Rakib, I did it previously, and works fine. But, I want to actually call a PUT method and want to execute it!

Comment: @OrbachinUjbuk, can you please update your question then? Otherwise people will get confused.

Comment: @Rakib, I already have stated that, get/post are working well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly permit PUT requests to your endpoint unlike GET and POST. You should look into your .htaccess settings.
[This question addresses the same concern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25752881/5494427) and [this also](https://serverfault.com/questions/275512/put-request-results-in-403-forbidden-need-apache-to-allow-put-requests).

Comment: Thanks. I have done that too, did not work. Compelled to resolve it with POST!

Answer (score 0):

Config your apache virtual host by these conditions:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
    Require all granted
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
    Require all denied
</LimitExcept>
```

Maybe your problem solved.

Comment: Say me that your scripts handled by Apache or Nginx?

Comment: And what's the version of your Web server?